# Unable to re-append a text in an element (using JavaScript append) after removing text (using JavaScript remove)

Tags: javascript, html

How do I use JavaScript append() and remove() to append and remove a element? Currently, my code is able to append the text for the div element when the user clicks 'Append Text' and remove the text from the  element when the user clicks 'Remove Text'.

But this happens only one round - meaning that after removing the text when user clicks 'Remove Text', the text cannot be re-appended when user clicks 'Append Text' again. I do not know why JavaScript append() does not work after removing the text from div element using remove.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Using JavaScript append() & remove () </h1>

<div id="demo"> </div>  <!-- text is appended & removed here -->

<button onclick="appendText()"> Append Text </button>

<button onclick="removeText()"> Remove Text </button>

<script>

var myobj = document.getElementById("demo");

function appendText() 
{

     //var myobj = document.getElementById("demo");
     myobj.append("Just a text");

}

function removeText() 
{
     //var myobj = document.getElementById("demo");
     myobj.remove();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Would you guys explain using the pure JavaScript (not JQuery) approach on where I have gone wrong cause I only know JavaScript. Based on my research on my problem I've done, nearly all of the solutions are in JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending a text node, but the `#demo` you select is the parent element. Select down to the text node first and remove it instead.

```js
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");

function appendText() {
  demo.append("Just a text");
}

function removeText() {
  demo.childNodes[demo.childNodes.length - 1].remove();
}
```

```html
<h1> Using JavaScript append() & remove () </h1>

<div id="demo"></div>
<!-- text is appended & removed here -->

<button onclick="appendText()"> Append Text </button>

<button onclick="removeText()"> Remove Text </button>
```

or clear the textContent

```js
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");

function appendText() {
  demo.append("Just a text");
}

function removeText() {
  demo.textContent = '';
}
```

```html
<h1> Using JavaScript append() & remove () </h1>

<div id="demo"></div>
<!-- text is appended & removed here -->

<button onclick="appendText()"> Append Text </button>

<button onclick="removeText()"> Remove Text </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.remove()` delete the element. So instead of it you should try using `.innerHTML` property.